# How to stop Android TextToSpeech when there is a phone call come in

Tags: android, audio, sdk, media-player, voice

My android app got rejected by Amazon because of this reason.

I have this TextToSpeech playing while the phone call come in.  They wanted me to stop playing.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service or activity that implement TextToSpeech register for PhoneStateListener and in your PhoneStateListener in onCallStateChanged call the TextToSpeech class stop() method for state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING.